# Why its gets error when my input string ends with spaces..?

Tags: java, string, indexoutofboundsexception

// Count total no of words in String

```
class Word
{
    static int Wordcount(String k)
    {

        int count=0; 
        char ch[]=k.toCharArray();
        for(int i=0;i<k.length();i++)
        {
            if(ch[i]==32 && ch[i+1]!=32)
            {
                count++;
            }
        }
        return(++count);
    }

    public static void main(String... s)
    {
        String k="java is a programming lan";
        /* if input string is "java is a prog lan    " then its gives//Exception                   
        */
        int b=Wordcount(k);
        System.out.println("Your input String has "+b +" words");
    }
}
```

// Exception aati h agr string khtm ho ri h space se

Comment: Why don't you use String.split() method to get the word count?

Comment: Saying `ch[i] == 32` is very confusing. You're comparing a `char` to an `int`, and not everyone as their ASCII table memorized. Say `ch[i] == ' '` instead.

Answer (score 0):

```
if(ch[i]==32 && ch[i+1]!=32)
```

If `ch[i]` is the last character in the string, and the code tries to check `ch[i+1]`, then you are outside the string's range, and you get an error.

If you want your condition to match spaces at the end of the string, then you can use

```
if (ch[i]==32 && (i+1 == ch.length || ch[i+1]!=32))
```

If you want your condition to match only if there is a non-space character after, then you can use

```
if (ch[i]==32 && i+1 < ch.length && ch[i+1]!=32)
```

Answer (score 0):

You are checking the current index and the next index at the same time with this condition:

```
if(ch[i]==32 && ch[i+1]!=32)
```

If you are on the last character and it's a space, then `ch[i+1]!=32` will be evaluated, causing the exception.

To resolve this, make sure you're not at the end of the array when checking index `i+1`.

```
if(ch[i]==32 && i < k.length() - 1 && ch[i+1]!=32)
```